# How to convert a bookmarklet into a Greasemonkey userscript?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, bookmarklet, userscripts, tampermonkey

Is there a easy way to do this. And is there anything that needs to be changed due to differences in how it is ran?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this:

1. Run the bookmarklet code through a [URL decoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).  so that `javascript:alert%20('Hi%20Boss!')%3B`, for example, becomes:
   `javascript:alert ('Hi Boss!');`
2. Strip the leading `javascript:` off.   Result: `alert ('Hi Boss!');`
3. Add this code to the end of your Greasemonkey file.  For example, create a file named,
   ***Hello World.user.js***, with this code:

   ```
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name            Hello World!
   // @description     My first GM script from a bookmarklet
   // @include         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
   // @grant           none
   // ==/UserScript==

   alert ('Hi Boss!');
   ```
4. Open ***Hello World.user.js*** with Firefox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> ).   Greasemonkey will prompt to install the script.
5. Now the bookmarklet code will run automatically on whatever pages you specified with the `@include` and `@exclude` directives.
6. **Update:**  To ensure maximum compatibility, use the `@grant none` directive that was added in later versions of Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey.

---

IMPORTANT:

- The userscript will run much sooner than you could ever activate a bookmark.  Normally, this is not a problem.
- But in some cases, you might need to **wait for some part of the page to fully load**.
  In that case, you can [use techniques/utilities like *waitForKeyElements*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508).
- See also, [Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site) .
- If you still can't get your new script to work, be sure to read [My very simple Greasemonkey script is not running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083669/my-very-simple-greasemonkey-script-is-not-running).  Follow the steps and **include the specified information** in any question you open about problems with the new script.

Comment: This is great, but this will run automatically on every page. All of my bookmarklets are things I only want to activate sometimes (like bookmarking the page on Pinboard or looking it up on the Wayback Machine). How would you make it only execute when I want it to?

Comment: @NickS, that's what [the `@include`, `@exclude`, and `@match` directives](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_include) are for.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: I mean I want to be on a page, think "hey, I want to look this up on the Wayback Machine", click *something*, and execute my script (opens a new tab with a Wayback Machine search for the current url).
What do I click? How does the script know when to open the tab?

Comment: @NickS, this is beyond the scope of comments. Open a new question if needed. But beware that what you're asking has probably been covered in other Q&A's.

Comment: Okay, that's cool, maybe I will. I just realized one possibility is adding an entry to the right-click context menu, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good article to [avoid common pitfalls](https://web.archive.org/web/20180522164626/http://archive.oreilly.com:80/pub/a/network/2005/11/01/avoid-common-greasemonkey-pitfalls.html?page=3) because of differences between "normal" JS and Greasemonkey.

The most important things at the beginning:

- Do not use functions as strings, like: <s>`window.setTimeout("my_func()", 1000);`</s> but rather
  `window.setTimeout(my_func, 1000);` or
  `window.setTimeout(function(){doSomething(); doSomethingOther();}, 1000);`
- Do not set <s>`element.onclick`</s> but rather `element.addEventListener("click", my_func, true);`
- Some code that normally returns various DOM objects, in Greasemonkey environment returns those objects wrapped in XPCNativeWrapper. This is for security reasons.

  Some methods and properties are "transparent" and you can invoke them on wrapped object, but some not. Read in the mentioned article about how to circumvent this; you can also use (this is not recommended generally, but for testing etc.) wrappedJSObject property. It is, when `obj.something`/`obj.something()`  doesn't work in Greasemonkey, try `obj.wrappedJSObject.something`/`obj.wrappedJSObject.something()`.