# Why won't this bookmarklet convert to a userscript?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, userscripts

I'm trying to convert a [bookmarklet](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200608/light_text_on_dark_background_vs_readability/):

```
javascript:(function(){var newSS, styles='* { background: white ! important; color: black !important } :link, :link * { color: #0000EE !important } :visited, :visited * { color: #551A8B !important }'; if(document.createStyleSheet) { document.createStyleSheet(%22javascript:'%22+styles+%22'%22); } else { newSS=document.createElement('link'); newSS.rel='stylesheet'; newSS.href='data:text/css,'+escape(styles); document.getElementsByTagName(%22head%22)[0].appendChild(newSS); } })();
```

to a userscript to use with Opera and Midori. I followed the steps in [How to convert a bookmarklet into a Greasemonkey userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906025/how-to-convert-a-bookmarklet-into-a-greasemonkey-userscript) but without much luck. Here's the code that I come up with, but which doesn't seem to function:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Darklooks
// @description   Eye-friendly colorscheme attempting to emulate Darklooks
// @include       http://*
// @include       https://*
// @include       about:blank*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
var newSS, styles='* { background: #555753 ! important; color: #D3D7CF !important } :link, :link * { color: #00008B !important } :visited, :visited * { color: #551A8B !important }'; if(document.createStyleSheet) { document.createStyleSheet("javascript:'" styles "'"); } else { newSS=document.createElement('link'); newSS.rel='stylesheet'; newSS.href='data:text/css,' escape(styles); document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newSS); 
} 
})();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there was a stray `javascript:` embedded in the code.

Anyway, try this.  It works, but I only tested on my primary browsers (Firefox and Chrome):

```
(function () {
    var newSS;
    var styles = '* { background: white ! important; color: black !important } :link, :link * { color: #0000EE !important } :visited, :visited * { color: #551A8B !important }';
    if (document.createStyleSheet) {
        document.createStyleSheet(styles);
    }
    else {
        newSS = document.createElement('link');
        newSS.rel = 'stylesheet';
        newSS.href = 'data:text/css,' + escape(styles);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newSS);
    }
} ) ();
```