# My very simple Greasemonkey script is not running?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, greasemonkey

I am having issues with this very basic Greasemonkey script, most likely with the metadata configuration.

Here is the full source of the basic file

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Google Hello
// @namespace   https://google.com
// @description Basic Google Hello
// @include     *
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

alert("hi google!");
```

This script should run when I access Google.com, but the alert is not popping up. What is the issue?

I am attempting to run this script on Ubuntu with Firefox.

Comment: your namespace is set to https, try adjusting to just http

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that has no effect on the situation.

Comment: Strange. Runs fine on win7

Comment: Should I try chrome?

Comment: Also checkout Greasemonkey's troubleshooter page for Users: https://wiki.greasespot.net/Troubleshooting_(Users) and Script Authors: https://wiki.greasespot.net/Troubleshooting_(Script_Authors)

Comment: FYI, `@namespace` is part of the name for a script; but it doesn't tell it where to run. (It's not even a URL.) [Source](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40namespace)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**If `alerts()` are not firing,** chances are you may have clicked Firefox's `Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs` option, or set a browser preference (older versions of Firefox), or Firefox may have become unstable in memory.

## Universal Greasemonkey debug steps:

(With one step added for problems with `alert()`.)

1. **First make sure that the script is even firing for the page in question.**
   While browsing that page, **click on the down-triangle next to the Greasemonkey icon** (Alternatively, you can Open *Tools* -> *Greasemonkey* on the Firefox menu.) and verify that the expected script name appears and is checked. EG:
   [image: Greasemonkey states]
2. See if there **are any relevant messages/errors on [Firefox's *Browser Console*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)**.
   Activate the console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, or equivalent.

   Here's a screenshot showing how both messages and errors appear in the *Browser Console* -- caused by both the web page and the Greasemonkey script:
   [image: Sample Browser console results]
3. Open `about:config`, search for `capability.policy.default.Window.alert` and delete or reset the value, if it is found.
4. **Uninstall the Greasemonkey script.**
5. **Completely clear the browser cache.**
6. **Shutdown Firefox completely.**  Use *Task Manager*, or equivalent, to verify that there is no Firefox thread/task/process in memory.
7. **Restart Firefox.**
8. **Install the Greasemonkey script afresh.**
9. If it still doesn't work, create a **new Firefox profile** or try a **different computer** altogether.

## Additional issues:

1. **Please supply your *versions* of three things:** (1) The OS, (2) Firefox, (3) Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey or Scriptish, etc.
2. `@include *` means that **the script will fire for every page!**  This is almost always a poor practice.  (There are some exceptions, but your case is not one.)
3. **`@namespace` does not control where the page runs.**  The only thing `@namespace` does is allow more than one script to have the same name (as long as their `@namespace`s are different).  See [the `@namespace` documentation](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40namespace).
4. Avoid using `alert()` for debugging.  It's annoying and can mask timing problems.
   **Use `console.log()`.**  You can **see the results, and helpful error messages (hint, hint) on the *Browser Console*.**
5. **Google almost always uses/redirects to `www.google.com`** (For English USA users).  So, `// @include  https://google.com` will almost never work like you want.

   Recommend you use:

   ```
   // @match  *://www.google.com/*
   ```

   as a starting point.

   In Firefox Greasemonkey, you can also use the magic `.tld` to support most of Google's international domains, like so:

   ```
   // @include  http://www.google.tld/*
   // @include  https://www.google.tld/*
   ```

   Use both lines. Note that this does not perform as well as the `@match` line does.  So, if you only care about one nation/locale, just use `@match`.

---

### Putting it all together:

1. Uninstall your script.
2. Restart Firefox.
3. Install *this* script:

   ```
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name        Google Hello
   // @namespace   John Galt
   // @description Basic Google Hello
   // @match       *://www.google.com/*
   // @version     1
   // @grant       none
   // ==/UserScript==

   console.log ("Hi Google!");
   ```
4. Visit [Google](https://www.google.com/) and note the results on Firefox's Browser Console.
5. If there is still a problem, follow all of the debug steps above.
6. If there is still a problem, Open a new question and **supply ALL of the following:**

   1. The three versions, mentioned above.
   2. The *relevant* errors and messages you get on the *Browser Console*.
   3. The exact code and steps needed to duplicate the problem. **Make an [MCVE for this!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**
   4. A short summary of what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Freehand faces... awesome

Comment: Did not help. The problem is with ChatJax++. It works well in PaleMoon