# How to append to just the main body tag, in a page with iframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe, greasemonkey

I am developing a Greasemonkey script to append a div right after the body tag, here is the jQuery:

```
$("body:first").append (
  '<div id="btn" style="width:50px;display:block">SHOW</div>  <div id="gmPopupContainer" style="display:none">my text here</div>'
);
```

It works fine as long as there is only one body tag on the page, but a problem arises when there are iframes on the webpage. It appends to all the body nested in the iframes.

I've tried many jQuery selectors without success. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, **use [`@noframes`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40noframes) in your metadata block** to stop the script from running in iframes.

Or, in this case you can also use something like:

```
var topmostFramesMainBody = $(top.document.body).first ();
```

---

If that doesn't work, **provide the details specified in [*My very simple Greasemonkey script is not running?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083669/my-very-simple-greasemonkey-script-is-not-running).**
(Note that you should ALWAYS provide those details.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do `$("<div id="btn" ...>SHOW</div>").insertAfter('body');`

Comment: it doesn't work either,because it will insert after all body tags found on the web page including those in the iframes, i even tried $('document.body'). I need to refer to the body of the main document and discards all the rest

Comment: OK, give your main body an ID: `<body id="mainBody">...</body>` and then do `$("<div id="btn" ...>SHOW</div>").insertAfter('body.mainBody');`

Comment: i cannot give an id to the body since i am writing a cross site greasemonkey script so i dont control the web page.