# waitForKeyElements not waiting for ajax loaded data on some browsers?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-browser, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

In my script for Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey is working perfectly in Google Chrome but in Firefox this:

```
waitForKeyElements ("table#ID-rowTable tr td span._GAmD", replaceAffid);
```

is not waiting for AJAX loaded content.

Here is the relevant part of my script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        ChangeProvider
// @description Change Provider Name
// @include     https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/*
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

<snip>...

waitForKeyElements ("table#ID-rowTable tr td span._GAmD", replaceAffid);

<snip>...

function waitForKeyElements (
    selectorTxt,    /* Required: The jQuery selector string that
                        specifies the desired element(s).
                    */
    actionFunction, /* Required: The code to run when elements are
                        found. It is passed a jNode to the matched
                        element.
                    */
    bWaitOnce,      /* Optional: If false, will continue to scan for
                        new elements even after the first match is
                        found.
                    */
    iframeSelector  /* Optional: If set, identifies the iframe to
                        search.
                    */
) {
    var targetNodes, btargetsFound;

    if (typeof iframeSelector == "undefined")
        targetNodes     = $(selectorTxt);
    else
        targetNodes     = $(iframeSelector).contents ()
                                           .find (selectorTxt);

<snip>...
```

## The full code is [at pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/UNAjQ29r).

Comment: Having the full script at pastebin is great.  However, you still need enough code in the actual question to make an [mcve], so that people can replicate the problem.  Pastebin links rot away and without sufficient code in the question, it would become useless when the link goes bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem(s) is/are:

1. **`waitForKeyElements()` requires jQuery.**
2. Your **script must** either **provide jQuery (recommended)**, or use `@grant none` mode and be running on a page that already uses jQuery (a brittle way to do things, AKA "time-bomb code").
3. **Tampermonkey has a bug** and possible security weakness whereby it doesn't always 
   sandbox properly.  This means that the script can (sometimes) see the page's jQuery, even when `@grant` is not `none.`  This allowed the script to run in Chrome (for now) but is a very dicey thing to depend on.
4. **Firefox properly sandboxes** the scope when you use `@grant GM_ ...` so the **script cannot see the page's jQuery.**
5. If you had [looked at Firefox's *Browser Console*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083669/my-very-simple-greasemonkey-script-is-not-running/31086018#31086018), you **would have seen error messages** pointing you to the problem.

The solution is: **Don't use waitForKeyElements without `@require`ing jQuery!**
In fact, you should require both libraries, [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508), as it (A) Runs faster, (B) Only fetches the code once, when you install/edit the userscript, and (C) makes for cleaner, easier to grok code.

So, your entire script would become something like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        GoogleAnalytics Change Provider
// @description Change Provider Name
// @include     https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/*
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==
var providers = new Array ();

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/t2_provider_list",
    onload: function (response) {
        var provider_list = JSON.parse (response.responseText);

        for (i = 0; i < provider_list.length; i++) {
            providers[provider_list[i].analytics_prefix] = provider_list[i].provider_name;
        }
        waitForKeyElements ("table#ID-rowTable tr td span._GAmD", replaceAffid);
    }
} );

/*--- replaceAffid ():  Match the fields with a given pattern 
and replace with the provider name and affid
*/
function replaceAffid () {
    console.log (providers);
    var regExp = /([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)---([a-z,A-Z,0-9,_,-]+)/g;

    var spans = document.evaluate ("//span[contains(@class, '_GAmD') and not(contains(@class, '_GAe'))]/text()", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    console.log (spans);
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.snapshotLength; i++) {
        match = regExp.exec (spans.snapshotItem (i).textContent);

        if (match != null) {
            if (typeof providers[match[1]] === undefined) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                spans.snapshotItem (i).textContent = "Provider: " + providers[match[1]] + " \n\r  Affid: " + match[2];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Finally, it looks like you pasted in an old version of waitForKeyElements.
[Since May of 2012](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891/revisions), that function has had this text near the top:

> IMPORTANT: This function requires your script to have loaded jQuery.

If you grabbed your copy of the function from [one of my old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8283815/331508), I apologize.  I just updated it to avoid a repeat of this confusion.