# Can't remove grayscale filter on some webpage

Tags: css, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

My code to remove grayscale filter(s):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Remove Grayscale
// @namespace    Remove Grayscale
// @description  Remove Grayscale
// @version      1
// @author       You
// @match        http*://*/*
// ==/UserScript==

//var script = document.createTextNode("<style type='text/css'>html, body, img {filter:none !important; -webkit-filter:none !important;}</style>");
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type="text/css";
script.innerHTML="html, body, img {filter:grayscale(0) !important; -webkit-filter:grayscale(0) !important;}";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
//document.head.appendChild(script);

//document.head.setAttribute("style","filter:none !important; -webkit-filter:none !important;");
document.body.setAttribute("style","filter:grayscale(0) !important; -webkit-filter:grayscale(0) !important;");
document.html.setAttribute("style","filter:grayscale(0) !important; -webkit-filter:grayscale(0) !important;");
```

It didn't work on [pptvhd36.com](https://www.pptvhd36.com/).
What is wrong?

Comment: It's document.documentElement, not document.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

1. Always [look in the browser/error console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31086018/331508).  If you had, you would have seen errors like:

   > document.html is undefined

   You can't set `<html>` styles that way.
2. When merely overriding CSS, [the Stylish extension](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stylish/info) is available for most browsers and is the faster easier choice.
3. For userscripts, go ahead and use `GM_addStyle`.

Anywho, this script works and gets rid of most of the gray (note that some pics are uploaded in black and white):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        pptvhd36.com, Remove Grayscale
// @match       https://www.pptvhd36.com/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( `
    html {
        filter:grayscale(0) !important;
        -webkit-filter:grayscale(0) !important;
    }
` );
```